# Paypal: should I create a new plan for every new subscription request?

Tags: php, paypal-rest-sdk

Right now I am following these steps to create new subscriptions through `PayPal REST API` -

1. Create a plan
2. Activate the plan
3. Create a billing agreement
4. Execute the billing agreement

Now, in step 1 (create a plan) I have to pass redirect URL and cancel URL which has unique identifiers that are used to save the details to the database. The identifiers are user_id and artifact_id which changes for all new subscriptions. That is why I am forced to create a new plan every time.

My questions:
- Is this the right workflow?

Regards
Faisal

Answer (score 1):

The API which you are using `Billing Plan and Agreement` is now deprecated, Check this in official documentation https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/payments.billing-agreements/v1/

[image]

You should use Paypal's new Subscription API, which documented here https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/subscriptions/v1/. 
This approach is also similar to which you are using

You can create a new Plan for every new Subscription until there is not any change in Plan in the future.